# Windows 10 Bootable USB failure

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, usb

I'm trying to install Windows 10 on a recently built computer. To do this, I downloaded the ISO file and created a bootable USB FAT32 USB drive using UnetBootin. I tested the USB drive on my normal computer, and was able to boot to it just fine. However, when I try to boot from the USB drive on the new computer, I get a blue error screen with the following message:

"Recovery - Your PC/Device needs to be repaired. An unexpected error has occured.

Error Code 0xc000000e

You'll need to use recovery tools...

Press Enter to try again
Press F8 for Startup Settings
Press Esc for UEFI Firmware Settings"

I have searched the error code and it seems to be mostly associated with a corrupted boot section of the drive. However, I know this is not the case because I can boot from the USB drive on other computers.

Pressing F8 for startup settings just refreshes the error screen and does not take me to a settings menu. Pressing Esc for UEFI Firmware settings shuts down the computer.

Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to humor me, try using rufus instead of unetbootin. Could solve the problem.

Comment: I am running linux mint on my other computer, so I do not have access to Rufus (barring Wine)

Comment: Damn, that might be a problem... Anyhow I'm under the impression that your files were corrupted, this is either indicative of a bug in unetbootin or a faulty usb drive. You could try just writing it all again the same way to see if it'll work then. If it doesn't, see this question for alternatives to unetbootin https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312488/how-to-create-bootable-windows-10-image-in-debian (the most promising ones look like woeusb and mkisofs)

Comment: My thought was that the files were corrupted, but then that doesn't explain why the drive is bootable on one computer but not the other. And I can switch back and forth several times and consistently boot from the drive on my old computer and fail to boot on my new computer. I'm currently making a linux boot usb to try and see how that goes

Comment: I've seen flashdrives work on some PCs yet not on others because of contact issues in the flashdrive connectors.

Comment: Unebootin or any other tool in Linux, except MKUSB does not work with the new Windows ISOs. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Windows_USB_install_drive